# SortBy without final cannonical ordering

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

How can I `SortBy` a list without final cannonical ordering? E.g. `SortBy[{9, 1, 2, 5, 3, 7}, # Boole[# >= 6] & ]` returns `{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}` but I want `{1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 9}`.

Comment: This is surely a dupe, but the way to ensure *stable sorting* in this situation is to do `SortBy[{9, 1, 2, 5, 3, 7}, {# Boole[# >= 6] &}]`.

Comment: Why does this work? I am unable to find a documentaton about this structure.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690/499167) great answer by Andrew Moylan, to the SO question [Stable Sorting, ie, Minimally-Disruptive Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3304632/499167), may be of interest

Comment: @user1066 Clear explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332690). Yes, the documentation could mention this; I encourage you to [send that suggestion to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).

Comment: @J.M. IMO this is an important one, especially for future visitors to the site. Maybe you should make it an answer?  I don't think it is a duplicate here

Comment: @user I agree it is important, but I also dimly recall someone (perhaps Wizard or Leonid) writing about this at length on this site, so I am reluctant to write an answer. But I am having trouble finding that answer at the moment...

Comment: In addition `lst[[OrderingBy[lst, {# Boole[# >= 6] &} ]]]===SortBy[lst, {# Boole[# >= 6] &} ]` (but I can't find any reference to this in the [OrderingBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html) documentation)

Comment: you can also use  `#[[Ordering[# UnitStep[# - 6]]]] &@lst`